# Google map is not showing in partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, partial-views

I am trying to implement google map in a partial view and trying to call partial view on a page 
here is my google map script which I placed on a main view

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDLhntIiMFhAoHu5XtrxDuh4EeNbm2ZuH0&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initAutocomplete()
        {

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
                {
                center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });
            console.log('map', map);
            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });

            var markers = [];
            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
            // more details for that place.
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                if (places.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Clear out the old markers.
                markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                });
                markers = [];

                // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                places.forEach(function (place) {
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                        return;
                    }
                    var icon = {
                        url: place.icon,
                        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };
                    // Create a marker for each place.
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    }));

                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        // Only geocodes have viewport.
                        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    }
                    var address = $('#pac-input').val();
                    //document.getElementById('pac-input');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (res) {
                            latitude = res.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                            longitude = res.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                        }
                    });
                });
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
        }
```

And here is my HTML which is placed in partial view

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label>Type a location to Search on Map</label>
            <input type="text" id="pac-input" class="form-control" ng-model="MyLocations.Location" required>
            <div class="selectlocatinonmap" id="map">
            </div>
    </div>
```

I have placed this script  on a page where I have to call a partial view but google map is not working on a partial view
I am attaching the image also 
please take a look 
[image]

however console is not showing any error.

Comment: Can you pass center value like this once, and let me know, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),

Comment: i already place center value over there plase take a look in my code in initAutocomplete function

Comment: I told change that line from this, center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 }, to new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195), and check once.

Comment: not working 
i done this
 var map = new google.maps(document.getElementById('map'), 
                {
                center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });

Comment: Bro! You are not getting my point what I'm trying to tell you. Please change the line in your code center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195} to new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195), That's it. Rest code will be as it is. And check once and let me know.

Comment: sir still not working nor showing any error in console.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because when the callback function that generate maps is called, the map container is hidden. You can call the init map callback on click on the button that shows your form, after the fading or sliding effects are done.

**EDIT**

```
$('#my_button_wich_show_form').click(initAutocomplete);
```

Remember to delete callback param from maps url. If you use some effects before showing your modal, call the initAutocomplete function after the effects are done.

In your initAutocomplete function you have to check if #map is empty so you can execute your script or just trigger the map resize event :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initAutocomplete()
    {
        if( !$('#map').is(':empty') ){
            google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
            return false;
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
            {
            center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        var map = this.map;
        console.log('map', map);
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            // Clear out the old markers.
            markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = [];

            // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(function (place) {
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                    return;
                }
                var icon = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };
                // Create a marker for each place.
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                }));

                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    // Only geocodes have viewport.
                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
                var address = $('#pac-input').val();
                //document.getElementById('pac-input');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (res) {
                        latitude = res.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        longitude = res.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                    }
                });
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }
```

Comment: callback function is calling at the time of pageload

Comment: you can also call only the map resize function when the form is completely loaded, this will reload the map.

Comment: yes, it's been the problem. You can call the function on click, and delete the callback=initAutocomplete in your url params

Comment: please put your answer i would be very thankful to you if that's works

Comment: a better solution it's to load maps at the click, using getScript. This will avoid to wait for google maps at the page load

Comment: $('#my_button_wich_show_form').click(function(){
initAutocomplete();
})

Comment: this will work only if you haven't fading or sliding effects on your form. If you have effects, you have to wait that the form is completely showed, using callbacks on your fading/sliding animation or a timeout

Answer (score 0):

Run Fiddler it's free  and see if your request is getting to googgle.  Based on your screenshot I don't see any xhr to google mapping api.  I think your being blocked somewhere.

Comment: i think u may fail to add the css file ang google api

Comment: Would css prevent the map from loading or just make it look funny?